# How to use not declared string in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

This is simple nasm "Hello World" program.

```
section .text
    global _start       
_start:                     
    mov edx, len    
    mov ecx, msg    
    mov ebx, 1      
    mov eax, 4      
    int 0x80        
    mov eax, 1      
    int 0x80        

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa 
len equ $ - msg
```

But can I `mov` string into `ebx` without creating section `.data`?

Example:

```
mov ecx, "Hello World"
```

Is this possible to do?

I tried something like

```
wordvar dw      123
```

but I get an error.

Comment: NASM does allow you to load character operands into registers. However, this is limited to 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, which are equal to 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, and a byte can hold one ASCII codepoint. The size depends on the operation and register you're using. Eg `mov ecx, "ABCD"` will load into the `ecx` register. If you did `variable: db "ABCD"` in a data section then `mov ecx, dword [variable]` would result in the same data as the `mov ecx, "ABCD"` (This is not the case for all assembly dialects but is so for x86 NASM.)

Comment: "I tried something like `wordvar dw      123` but I get an error."   Can you expand on what that means?  What error, what context, how does it elide the data declaration you're trying to avoid?

Comment: You can `push`-immediate data onto the stack and pass a pointer to that, if you want.  That's a common technique for shellcode because it has to be self-contained.  Or for strings only a couple bytes long, if optimizing for total size it might be smaller to just have the data, not an address plus the data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes/no:

- Yes, it is not compulsory to put data into the `.data` section. Your program will work just fine if `msg` was in the `.text` section (as is, *after* the [`exit(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html), so it isn’t treated as instruction code). 
   Beware, `.text` is read-only. Read [ELF extensions to the `SECTION` Directive](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc8.html#section-8.9.2) to learn more about this and other standard sections.
- No, it is not possible, because [`write(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) will expect a *memory* *address* to write to the specified FD, not just the contents of a register. Writing in your Hello World `mov ecx, 'ABCD'` loads the “address” `0x44434241` which is obviously wrong.